# Find same value in foreach and join PHP

Tags: php, foreach

i want to detect same value in array, join and back result with different class, in this example there is two times letter 'a' so i need to back as final result only one time letter 'a' but should be with different class.

So basically if there is more than one same letter i need to join it into one and add different class.

```
$array = 'a,b,v,g,h,y,a';   
function buildTag2s($var) {
    $tags = explode(',',$var);
    foreach($tags as $i) {
        $string .= '<span class="one">'.$i.'</span>';
    }
    return $string;
} 
echo buildTag2s($array)
```

I have try to add inside foreach array_key_exists but does not work.

Output should be

```
<span class="two">a</span>
<span class="one">b</span>
<span class="one">v</span>
<span class="one">g</span>
<span class="one">h</span>
<span class="one">y</span>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what the intended result is. Are you looking to increment the `one` in your `<span>` class each time the loop iterates over... and an `a` is found?? Could you please add the expected output, perhaps?

Comment: If there is same value class should be 'two' for example.

Comment: where is `two` in your code?

Comment: I need to find way to add different class that actually is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, count the values, then before looping remove the duplicates.

```
<?php
$array = explode(',', 'a,b,v,g,h,y,a'); 

$stat = array_count_values($array);
foreach (array_unique($array) as $value) {
    echo '<span class="'.($stat[$value] > 1 ? 'two' : 'one').'">'.$value.'</span>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result

```
<span class="two">a</span>
<span class="one">b</span>
<span class="one">v</span>
<span class="one">g</span>
<span class="one">h</span>
<span class="one">y</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way.....

```
<?php

$array = 'a,b,v,g,h,h,h,h,y,y,y,a';


function buildTag2s ( $var )
{
    $item = array ( '', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight' );

    $keep = array ( );

    $send = '';

    $tags = explode ( ',', $var );

    foreach ( $tags as $i )
    {
        if ( ! isset ( $keep[$i] ) )
        {
            $keep[$i] = count ( array_keys ( $tags, $i ) );

            $send .= '<span class="' . $item[$keep[$i]] . '">'.$i.'</span>';
        }
    }

    return $send;
}

echo buildTag2s ( $array );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will give you a solution.

```
<?php

$array = 'a,b,v,g,h,y,a';   
function buildTag2s($var) {
    $string = NULL;
    $tags = explode(',',$var);
    $stat = array_count_values($tags);
    foreach(array_unique($tags) as $i) {
        $string .= '<span class="'.($stat[$i] > 1 ? 'two' : 
        'one').'">'.$i.'</span>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
   return $string;
  } 
 echo buildTag2s($array)
?>
```

result:

```
<span class="two">a</span>
<span class="one">b</span>
<span class="one">v</span>
<span class="one">g</span>
<span class="one">h</span>
<span class="one">y</span>
```